# How to print infomation in the get_gradient function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to change the `get_gradients` method of Adam to execute gradient Centralization, the following code is from https://keras.io/examples/vision/gradient_centralization/

My question is why the code `print('ttt')` in method `get_gradients` prints nothing when fit function is executing?
`print('dddd')` works and print dddd in screen.

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf

class GCAdam(Adam):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-7, amsgrad=False, name='Adam', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=epsilon, amsgrad=amsgrad, name=name, **kwargs)
        print('dddd')
   
    def get_gradients(self, loss, params):
        # We here just provide a modified get_gradients() function since we are
        # trying to just compute the centralized gradients.

        grads = []
        gradients = super().get_gradients()
        
        print('ttt')
        for grad in gradients:
            grad_len = len(grad.shape)
            if grad_len > 1:
                axis = list(range(grad_len - 1))
                grad -= tf.reduce_mean(grad, axis=axis, keep_dims=True)
            grads.append(grad)

        return grads


optimizergc = GCAdam(learning_rate=1e-4)

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizergc, metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1,verbose=1)
```

Comment: `print` can't work in graph mode, try `tf.print` it should work.

Comment: I've tried tf.print as your suggestion,it didn't work too. function model.fit executed as if it didn't call the GCAdam.get_gradient.

Comment: The docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#get_gradients) say `Should be used only in legacy v1 graph mode.`,